# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have very little code and getting this error when creating data migrations.

```
PS C:\Users\username\source\repos\ToDoAPI\ToDoAPI> dotnet ef migrations add initialmigration
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.SnapshotModelProcessor.<>c.<.ctor>b__3_1(FieldInfo p)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.UnionWith(IEnumerable`1 other)
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.SnapshotModelProcessor..ctor(IOperationReporter operationReporter, IModelRuntimeInitializer modelRuntimeInitializer)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object obj, Span`1 copyOfArgs, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithFewArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opt =>
    opt.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqliteConnection")));

var app = builder.Build();
```

ToDo.cs

```
public class ToDo
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string? ToDoName { get; set; }
}
```

Data

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) 
    { 

    }

    public DbSet<ToDo> ToDos => Set<ToDo>();
}
```

I don't know where this conversion is taking place which is generating build error.

Comment: This is the base convention for adding ```DbSet``` in EF
```public DbSet<ToDo> ToDos { get; set; }``` I don't if this cause your issue, but you can try it

Answer (score 1):

I had same error.

Upgraded `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` to version `5.2.0` and downgraded `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` from `9.0.0-preview.1.24081.2` to `8.0.2`. Also updated `dotnet-ef` tool to `8.0.2` from `7.0.3`.

Hope it will help you.